# Am I a British citizen overseas or just a UK British citizen?

Tags: visas, usa, terminology, uk-citizens, saudi-citizens

I live in Saudi-Arabia and I have a British passport and a Saudi passport. I'm applying for a US visa with my British passport. What are the requirements?
And am I a British citizen overseas or just a UK British citizen?

Comment: Your passport will tell you what kind of citizen you are on the first page.

Comment: What kind of visa? Tourist? Business? Work permit? Have you read the official requirements?

Comment: If you do not know what are you? how are we suppose to know?

Comment: @MeNoTalk I would guess i has to do with residency, but that should be stated explicitly.

Comment: "And am I a British citizen overseas or just a UK British citizen?" Where does it ask this? There's such a thing as a "British citizen", as well as "British Overseas Territories citizen", and much less commonly "British Overseas citizen", "British subject", "British National (Overseas)", and "British protected person". In general, as a British passport holder you are almost certainly a "British citizen"; unless you're connected with Hong Kong in which case you might be "British National (Overseas)".

Comment: I see nothing in the question about "multiple entry" so I am removing that tag. If it's important, please add relevant info to the question. I can only guess you intended the "dual nationality" tag?

Answer (score 9):

I would guess that if you are not aware of the distinction, you are a British citizen. Which class of British nationality you hold would be indicated on your passport. For example, here is a British Citizen passport:

[image: British Citizen passport]

A British Subject passport:

[image: British subject passport]

And a British National (Overseas) passport:

[image: British National (Overseas) passport]

Beside other differences, note that “British Citizen”, “British Subject”, etc. is explicitly written under the “Nationality” rubric on the identification page.

If it says anything else that “British Citizen”, you are not eligible for the visa waiver program and will need a visa to travel to the US. From the [UK governement's foreign travel advice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/usa/entry-requirements):

> The US Visa Waiver Programme (VWP) allows most British Citizen passport holders to visit the US for up to 90 days. The types of journey that are permissible under the VWP include tourism, certain types of business visit and transit to another country. If you have a British passport that describes your nationality as something other than ‘British Citizen’ you will need to get a visa.

Beyond that, the requirements to get a visa will depend on the type of visa and while some applications might be assessed more carefully than others, formally I don't think they differ depending on citizenship.

Comment: From a privacy point of view it might be good to also blank out some parts of the other passport. If you found them online, it might be helpfull to state a source. +1 for this answer though.

Comment: It is more or less nuts to post scans of a passport. The damage is done but you should erase the numbers at least.  If these were fake or demo images, fair enough.

Comment: @JoeBlow You can easily find these passports on Wikipedia as well. I don't know how privacy concerns are handled there.

Comment: If you are saying, it was not a passport relating to Relaxed - it was an example he found online - then, fair enough, there's no danger to Relaxed.  I just really think it's a "bad precedent" though to post any documents with **any identification number at all** How would the person in the passport feel if they found this page one day?  And have you used "google image search" lately - it's terrifying.  I work with big data sometimes and am generally terrified  :/

Comment: The pictures come from Wikipedia by way of Google image. Incidentally, they all seem to be emergency passports that have long expired.

Comment: The middle passport is issued to "A N Other" so is most likely a sample document.